# Why can't I login to my Openfire administration console after initial installation?

Tags: openfire

> Login failed: make sure your username and password are correct and that you're an admin or moderator.

Even when the password is right and the user is the same as what I already have, I still can't log in. Why?

Comment: Same problem here.  I've seen at http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/35034 that you are supposed to be able to change the /usr/local/openfire/conf/openfire.xml, but whenever I do this, that file deletes my entry, and I'm back to where I started.  I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: Installed using installer on Windows 7 machine, and I have the same problem.  In both the Mac and Windows 7 case, I used default settings, and the embedded db.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Upon reviewing this youTube video, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFHiRYRx79E, I finally figured out that the problem is that the admin username is "admin", **not** the email name we typed in during the install.  The password **is** the one we typed in during the install.

So in other words, use "admin" as the username, and the password you typed in during the install process, and you'll get in.

I'll admit this is not intuitive at all, since the note that the username is "admin" is buried inside what most people would skip as obvious instructions for entering username and password.

A second note is that if you use the embedded database, openfire 3.7.1 (Windows and Mac, possibly other platforms) will forget your admin password once you reboot.  I ran into this situation this morning after a reboot.  Followed these instructions to set up a separate database:  http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/database.html

This seems to finally do the trick, after repeated reboots today.

Answer (score 13):

At first I failed to login then,I tried login using

username: admin
password: *** what u had entered

and successfully i could do it.

Comment: thanks. and i did not set any user and pass: so user was admin like you said and pass was admin too.

Comment: need to restart server before trying this....the answer is helpful